# RV pad with 125amp sub-panel

Tags: subpanel

i built a RV pad for my brother.  I also built a small laundry/storage room next to pad.  I wanted him to pay for his own electricity so I ran 4 wires (2 hots, neutral, ground) from a 200 amp outside main panel (already bonded) to a meter box then to an outside 125 amp sub-panel. Both mounted to outside of storage room. The ground wire runs from 200 to 125. The sub-panel will be used as main disconnect.

Do I install the bonding screw in the sub-panel?

Note: the only other thing the main panel runs is the well and a booster pump. The wires were run underground in non-metallic electrical pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Subpanels and bonding screws do not go together.

The only way you would be using the bonding screw is if this meter was a separate *service* from the electric company, and he was paying the electric company directly.

Who is paid isn't the issue, but rather, it's how the service is delivered to you.  Power companies supply service which is potentially "floating" or subject to transformer leakage (lifting it to thousands of volts), and you cannot count on the power company's neutral being anywhere near ground.  And the power company does not supply ground.  That is why the first point beyond the power company must be grounded.

Remember the NEC rules that let you supply a 120V outlet, a TT30, a NEMA 14-30 and a NEMA 14-50 socket to the same pad, and only need to deliver 50A powe to all that. Idea being different RVs use different ones, but none use more than one at a time.